# using t4 template engine in production

Tags: asp.net, t4, production-environment

Planning of using t4 template in a production environment. I have not used this before either. I want to know if anything is required to be installed on the production server, are there any settings to be configured on the server, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about preprocessed (runtime) templates, then you don't need anything special on the server.

If you're talking about design-time (regular) T4 templates, then it's not a supported scenario.

If you're talking about an ASP.Net MVC website scaffolded via T4, then T4 isn't present in production.

Comment: Ultimately I need to generate some html markup and save it in a file. I'd need to associate this "template" with some data. So doesn't this requirement fall into the 1st category?!

Comment: If what you need to generate is HTML markup, then I suggest you go with the Razor engine instead.  See my blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2011/03/11/t4-vs-razor-what-s-the-skinny.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling your program where parts of the code is generated by T4 and placing the dll's on the server there is no difference from a program where you wrote all lines.

Comment: so you are saying we need not install anything on the production server; just copy pasting the dll into the bin folder is enough...am I right?

Comment: Yes that is enough for that scenario.    If you plan on creating changing html via the T4 generator - TextTransform.exe - then you have to get that working on the server - but in that case I would do as GarethJ suggests.